# How to select row that have the max price of each category in asc order?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions

The below is my table that has the item such as:

| ProductId | ProductName | Category | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Cadbury | C-1 | $12.00 |
| 21 | Nestle | C-1 | $13.99 |
| 73 | Amul | C-101 | $9.00 |
| 43 | Ghirardelli | C-101 | $10.88 |
| 105 | Snickers | C-2 | $18.90 |
| 677 | Amul | C-3 | $30.19 |
| 107 | Kit Kat | C-2 | $2.00 |
| 899 | Ferrero Rocher | C-4 | $5.00 |
| 209 | Spy | C-3 | $4.00 |
| 1014 | Naviluna | C-1 | $13.99 |
| 1561 | Twix | C-101 | $10.88 |

The output I want is :-

| ProductId | ProductName | Category | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Nestle | C-1 | $13.99 |
| 105 | Snickers | C-2 | $18.90 |
| 677 | Amul | C-3 | $30.19 |
| 899 | Ferrero Rocher | C-4 | $5.00 |
| 43 | Ghirardelli | C-101 | $10.88 |

If max prices are same then find the row with max price and min product_id group by category asc

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by price desc, product_id asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, Is the category sorted in asc? If so can you explain me about it.

Comment: @Sunny . . . Nothing in this answer orders by `category`.  Of course, that could be added to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing something like this:

**SET UP TEST DATA**

```
create table prices (productid, productname, category, price) as
select   13, 'Cadbury'       , 'C-1'  , '$12.00' from dual union all
select   21, 'Nestle'        , 'C-1'  , '$13.99' from dual union all
select   73, 'Amul'          , 'C-101',  '$9.00' from dual union all
select   43, 'Ghirardelli'   , 'C-101', '$10.88' from dual union all
select  105, 'Snickers'      , 'C-2'  , '$18.90' from dual union all
select  677, 'Amul'          , 'C-3'  , '$30.19' from dual union all
select  107, 'Kit Kat'       , 'C-2'  ,  '$2.00' from dual union all
select  899, 'Ferrero Rocher', 'C-4'  ,  '$5.00' from dual union all
select  209, 'Spy'           , 'C-3'  ,  '$4.00' from dual union all
select 1014, 'Naviluna'      , 'C-1'  , '$13.99' from dual union all
select 1561, 'Twix'          , 'C-101', '$10.88' from dual
;
```

**QUERY AND OUTPUT**

```
with prep as (
  select productid, productname, category, price,
         to_number(price, '$999.99') as num_price
  from   prices
)
select min(productid) keep (dense_rank first 
              order by num_price desc nulls last) as productid,
       min(productname) keep (dense_rank first
              order by num_price desc nulls last, productid) as productname,
       category,
       max(price) keep (dense_rank first 
              order by num_price desc nulls last) as price
from   prep
group  by category
order  by to_number(substr(category, instr(category, '-') + 1))
;

PRODUCTID PRODUCTNAME    CATEGORY PRICE 
--------- -------------- -------- ------
       21 Nestle         C-1      $13.99
      105 Snickers       C-2      $18.90
      677 Amul           C-3      $30.19
      899 Ferrero Rocher C-4      $5.00 
       43 Ghirardelli    C-101    $10.88
```